# How do I get back into my Terraria world?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I've spent a long time playing Terraria and I'm about to defeat Duke Fishron, but a new update came to my kindle fire HD tablet on July-15-16 and when I tried to log into my main world, it would load and then crash the game. But it lets me on my other less sophisticated non-main worlds.

Comment: You can't, there isn't anything you can do about it

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, there is no way you can recover it. My friends who played terraria reported that after the update, they are not able to recover. Try [contacting their support team](https://support.505games.com/support/home).